# XML content does not seem to be XML

Tags: xml, r

Above is the error I have when I was trying to read 80 xml files in a `for` loop. The problem is with `xmlParse`. It worked well with others, but only 1 file. I am not really understand about built function. I just want to ask how to skip `xmlParse` error.

> > xmlParse(file)
> >
> > Error: XML content does not seem to be XML: 'sample.part40.xml'

Comment: If you just want to skip this file and continue processing the rest, see `?try`.

Comment: I looked at it. But please tell me about the conditioning term that I could use like -- if(xmlParse(file[i]) == error)) try (i=i+1) -- or something like that. I am not sure. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When iterating over a list of files, if you see this error, it normally means the content of that specific file is not `xml`.  This happens often when the files have been scraped off the web (for example, one might be a generic 404 file instead with no `xml` content).

I normally use something like this:

```
 results <- lapply(listOfFiles, function(f)  
                {X <- try(xmlParse(f))
                 if (inherits(X, "try-error")) NA else X} )
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Ricardo. I found my problem.

Comment: Although it doesn't matter here, it's good practice to use `inherits(X, "try-error")` instead of `class(X) == "try-error"` because `class(X)` could have length greater than one.

Comment: @gsee, great catch (did you see what I just did there? ;)  thanks, code updated