# R : XML content does not seem to be XML

Tags: xml, r

I am parsing a XML file using R, but I always got the error saying the XML content does not seem to be XML, but the XML file truly contains XML data and even if I just put in one simple tag. Please see sample below

Any suggestion on how to resolve this?

R code :

```
xmlinfile = "sample.xml"
xml = xmlInternalTreeParse(xmlinfile)
```

sample.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <name>Sample</name>
</root>
```

Error :

```
Error: XML content does not seem to be XML: 'sample.xml'
```

As requested, below is what I got when I print the file before parsing:

```
 xmlinfile = "sample.xml"
 sampleFile<-file(xmlinfile,"w")
 print(sampleFile)

description     class      mode     text       opened     can read    can write 
"sample.xml"    "file"      "w"    "text"     "opened"      "no"        "yes"
```

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Related, but possibly not a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954817/xml-content-does-not-seem-to-be-xml?rq=1

Comment: Can you print the file before parsing it? Are you sure its opening *that* specific `sample.xml`?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr, I print the file after parsing and I got : > print(xml)
[1] "Error : XML content does not seem to be XML: 'sample.xml'\n"
attr(,"class")
[1] "try-error"
attr(,"condition")
<XMLInputError: XML content does not seem to be XML: 'sample.xml'>

Comment: Can you edit that output into your question. Also, it looks like you are still trying to parse the file, which is causing problems. Can you just open and print the file and show what is printed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks all for the comments and answers, I think I found the answer. My XML file is not in the same location as my R script that caused the problem.

But the error message does not seem to be correct or intuitive. But anyways, it works now.
Thank you all again. ;)

Comment: I had the same problem and solved it by using `setwd()` to the folder where my local XML file resided.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say, but that just works:

```
> library(XML)
> xmlinfile = "sample.xml"
> xml = xmlInternalTreeParse(xmlinfile)
> str(xml)
Classes 'XMLInternalDocument', 'XMLAbstractDocument' <externalptr>
```

Comment: where did you run it? I am using RStudio, is there any difference?

Comment: I ran it in R on the command line, but it would have been the same in RStudio :) If this comes up again, remember the getwd() and setwd() commands, they set the working environment for the R session.

Answer (score 1):

It works like this --> 1st Download, 2nd parse

```
file_q4<-"https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Frestaurants.xml"
discFile_q4<-"./data/q4_dat.xml"
download.file(file_q4, discFile_q4, method = "wget",quiet = TRUE)
dat_xml<-xmlInternalTreeParse(discFile_q4)
rootNode<-xmlRoot(dat_xml)
```

Done

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error when trying to use `readtext` on all the docx files in a folder when I realized I had some of those documents open.  After closing them all and restarting R, the function worked without getting the error.